# Can you use property subsitution in liquibase changelog?

Tags: postgresql, github-actions, liquibase, changelog

I am using github actions to run my liquibase deployments. I have variables that I want to substitute into my liquibase script during deployment the [liquibase article](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/property-substitution.html) here states that this should be possible. I have a changelog.json that simply includes the sql files like so:

```
"databaseChangeLog": [
    {
           "include":{"file": "path-to-sql/my_file.sql"}
    }
]
```

now in `my_file.sql` I have:

```
--changeset author:1
create user my-user with password ${MY_ENV};
```

However, I receive the error:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Migration failed for changeset my_file.sql:
    Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$"...
```

Any one come across this specific error with variable substitution? Is this just a syntax error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`-d`](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/home.html#changelog-properties) parameter,

> **-D<property.name>=<property.value>**    Pass a name/value pair for [substitution of ${} blocks](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/property-substitution.html) in the changelogs.

For example:

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset your.name:1 labels:example-label context:example-context
--comment: example comment
create table ${daTableName} (
    id int primary key auto_increment not null,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    address1 varchar(50),
    address2 varchar(50),
    city varchar(30)
)
--rollback DROP TABLE ${daTableName};
```

And the command:

```
liquibase update -DdaTableName=MySofExampleTable
```

Did work for me

[image: h2 example]

Note that this approach will log your variables in Github actions, and in your case the value represents a password so be carful with that, or you add this value to your `liquibase.properties` file, for example

```
parameter.daTableName=SomeTable
```

then you just run your liquibase commands without passing the `-d` parameter.

From Github actions side, you would fetch the secret, and ammend it to your properties file, for example:

```
jobs:
  foo:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "liquibase.MY_ENV=${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}" >> liquibase.properties
```

---

Or as a plan-B for some use-cases, you can use [`envsubst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) to replace your environment variables, for example:

```
jobs:
  foo:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "create user my-user with password \${MY_ENV};" > my-migration.template.sql
      - run: envsubst < my-migration.template.sql > my-migration.sql
        env:
         MY_ENV: bob
      - run: cat my-migration.sql
```

Result:

[image: jobs screenshot]

So you basically create actions (or scripts) that replace your environment variables, if you have multiple files you may do something like:

```
for f in $(find ./lqb-src -regex '.*\.sql'); do envsubst < $f > "./lqb-out/$(basename $f)"; done
```